# Why does the Taylor expansion of $e^x$ satisfy exponential properties?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Suppose I knew nothing about the function $e^x$. If I wanted to find a power series that was its own derivative, I would logically start with the constant term, and first start by setting it to $1$. Then, the next term should be the antiderivative of the first term, giving me $x$. Doing this again would give me $\frac{x^2}2$. Repeating this process over and over again, I would get
$$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\ldots=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$$
Graphing a few terms of this, I might notice that this looks more and more like an exponential the more terms I graph. If I prove that this function satisfies the exponential relationship $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$, I would be able to prove that this series is an exponential function. How would I prove this? After this, how would I prove that the base of this exponential function is $e$, which is defined as $\displaystyle{\lim_{n \to \infty}} (1+\frac1n)^n$?

Edit: After expanding $(1+x)(1+y)$ and $(1+x+\frac{x^2}2)(1+y+\frac{y^2}2)$, I can see how extra terms get taken care of when the next degree is added. However, my second question still stands.

Comment: Use log rules and show that the properties for the homomorphism hold.

Comment: I would prove the exponential property one degree at a time.

Comment: This is one of many ways to define the exponential function; then you prove the other definitions as properties. I think it's the approach Gleason takes in his Abstract Analysis text. https://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Abstract-Analysis-Andrew-Gleason/dp/0867202092

Comment: If you knew nothing about the exponential function, then how would you be able to develop its Taylor series representation?  What properties are you actually assuming to begin?

Comment: @MarkViola: I am not sure but it seems OP is just defining a function by a power series. And in the interior of region of convergence a power series is actually the Taylor series of its sum (this is not an obvious result btw).

Comment: Also if you want a function which is its own derivative then it is directly possible to show that it is essentially the exponential function. See this answer for more details: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292586/72031

Comment: @paramanandsingh Well, the OP seems to be using both the series and the ODE characterizations after stating that we know nothing about the function.

Comment: @MarkViola I was not trying to create the Taylor series. I started with a constant term of a power series, and then added the antiderivative of that term, and then the antiderivative of that next term, and so on. Logically, since this is an infinite series, this function should be its own derivative.

Comment: You have not answered the basic question, which is "What assumptions are you making with respect to the exponential function?"  You stated that you knew nothing.  Now, you seem to be assuming that $f$ is a funciotn such that $f'(x)=f(x)$.  But this is not sufficient since $g(x)=Af(x)$ also would satisfy $g'(x)=g(x)$ for all $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **[THIS ARTICLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characterizations_of_the_exponential_function) discusses six independent and equivalent characterizations of exponential function, $e^x$.**

---

The OP assumes that the exponential function is characterized as the function $f(x)$ that satisfies the ordinary differential equation

$$f'(x)=f(x)\tag 1$$

subject to the initial condition $f(0)=1$.

Inasmuch as $f'(x)=f(x)$, $\forall x$, then by induction $f\in C^\infty$ with $f^{(n)}(x)=f(x)$.  Hence, $f^{(n)}(0)=f(0)=1$ and the Taylor series for $f(x)$ is given by

$$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}\tag2$$

This establishes the equivalence of the solution of the ODE $(1)$ and the Taylor series representation $(2)$.

That is to say, if we name the function $f(x)$ that satisfies $(1)$, subject to $f(0)=1$, **the exponential function**, then **the exponential function** is represented by the Taylor series given in $(2)$.  Note that the converse is also true.

---

Next, the OP tacitly assumes that the exponential function is characterized by the functional equation

$$f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)\tag 3$$

And that if the Taylor series in $(2)$ satisfies $(3)$, then the Taylor series representation is the exponential function.

Other solutions presented on this page have already established (e.g., use of Cauchy Product) that $f(x)$ as given by $(2)$ satisfies the functional equation $(3)$.

---

> However, we have *not* shown that $f(x)$ as characterized by $(1)$, or $(2)$, or $(3)$ is the function $e^x$, where $e$ is defined as
>
> $$e=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

To do so, one first needs to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n=\left(\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right)^x =e^x\tag4 $$

If $x\in \mathbb{Q}$, then proof of $(4)$ is straightforward.  Then, by exploiting the density of the rational numbers, one can prove that $(4)$ is true for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

> Note that $(4)$ provides yet another unique characterization of the exponential function, which can be shown equivalent to $(1)$, $(2)$, and $(3)$.

Answer (score 6):

The first answer lies in [Cauchy products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) and the binomial theorem, which show that

$$e^xe^y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^ny^k}{n!k!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkx^{n-k}y^k=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(x+y)^n}{n!}=e^{x+y}$$

As per the second question, the proof can be lengthy and various, and many are outlined in

[The definition of e by limits of $(1+1/n)^n$ through series expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/901708/272831).

Answer (score 4):

By the Binomial theorem,

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,k!\,n^k}=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!\,n^k}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}(n-j)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac jn\right).$$

But

$$\left(1-\frac kn\right)^k\le\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(1-\frac jn\right)\le1$$
and for any $m\le n$,
$$\sum_{k=0}^m\frac1{k!}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^k\le\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^k\le\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le\sum_{k=0}^n\frac1{k!}.$$

Taking the limit $n\to\infty$,

$$\sum_{k=0}^m\frac1{k!}\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\le\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}.$$

This shows that $$e^1=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n.$$

Comment: This was nice. +1

Answer (score 1):

To prove $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$ recall the binomial formula

$$
(x+y)^k = \sum_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}x^iy^{k-i}
$$

plug this into the formula above for finite $k$, and you'll find that the sums are separable into two terms that multiply (after a simple substitution $(k-i)\mapsto j$). Send $k\to \infty$ and you'll have the final result.

The second part is a similar application of the binomial formula for finite $n$ to the expression $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$, but sending $n\to \infty$ gives you $f(1)$, which could be your definition of $e$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x) f(y) = \left( \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} \right) \left( \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{y^j}{j!}  \right) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \sum_{i+j=k} \frac{ x^i y^j }{i! j!} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!} \sum_{i+j=k} \binom{k}{i,j} x^i y^j  = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x+y)^k}{k!}  =f(x+y).
\end{eqnarray*}