# Proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=e$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I know that this sequence converges because it is increasing and bounded (well, this is the usual way to prove it). In some books, the number $e$ is defined to be this limit.

But in other books the number $e$ is defined this way:
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{n!}$$
and the exponential function
$$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac x{n!}$$

But my problem is to prove that both definitions are consistent. Assumig the second definition of $e$ and $e^x$, I have done this:

I define $f_n(x)=\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$. Then I take any compact interval $[a,b]$ and I show that the numeric sequence
$$\left\{\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\right\}_{n=1}^\infty$$
is monotonic and bounded for every $x\in[a,b]$. So the sequence of functions $f_n$ converges -pointwisely at least- in that interval. Let be $f$ the limit.

Now
$$f'_n(x)=\frac1nn\left(1+\frac xn\right)^{n-1}$$
and we see that $\lim f'_n=f$; therefore, $f'=f$.

Since $f(0)=1$, we deduce that $f(x)=e^x$.

This is not an exercise or anything like that, but I'd like to ensure if vevery step in my proof is correct.

I am specially dubious with the derivative of the sequence. Do I need uniform convergence to do that? How could I show it in this case?

Comment: Check Out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/860796/how-to-show-that-sum-n-0-infty-dfrac-1n-e. Related.

Answer (score 0):

$$f^{'}_{n}(x)=f_{n}(x)$$
You can show that this works for $e^{x}=f_{n}(x)$

I am also dubious about the stunt you pulled when you said "and we see that lim $f^{'}_{n}=f$, since $f(0)=1$, we deduce that $f(x)=e^{x}$" by your assumption I can deduce it is equal to $3^{x}$. You made a hasty conclusion and maybe a more broader explanation might ease the mind of yours

Comment: The correct equation is: $f_n'(x) = \frac{f_n(x)}{1 + \frac{x}{n}}$